# How to group JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

How to group JSON data using `group_name`

Json :

```
[
{"fullname":"fffffffff","email":"sss@gg","mobile":"3333333333","designation":"ggg","group_name":"engineers"},

{"fullname":"ddddddddddd","email":"sssg@gg","mobile":"3333333333","designation":"fffff","group_name":"programmers "},

{"fullname":"hhhhhhhhh","email":"email@hotmail.com","mobile":"020202028347","designation":"programmer","group_name":"engineers"},
]
```

Here I appended it dynamically to table.

jQuery:

```
 function (data) {
     $("#view_table").ViewTable('option', 'data', data);
 }
```

I managed to append data to table but it cannot be grouped and that why it shows undefined as shown in attached picture.

[image: json]

Comment: what is tha plugin you are using to display the table using json? is it DataTables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Comment: I am using JQuery to retrieve data from function in JSON format. So the function is like `public List<GroupUserList> GetData()`

Comment: 3 upvotes for what? can't get it.

Comment: anything you cannot get? I will explain it . my question is very simple and I just want to group json data by group_name and instead of showing undefined label as shown in attached picture I want to show group_name

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,JSfiddle* ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Underscore.js library to achieve this.

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(json, 'group_name');
```